# How do you transfer eth out of smart contract from etherscan?

Tags: solidity, ether, etherscan, smart-contract-wallets

I have eth on a smart contract from people minting our nfts. How do I transfer that eth out?

Can i do it on etherscan as long as I'm signed into the address that uploaded the contract to mainnet?

Here is etherscan link to contract. https://etherscan.io/address/0xe52cfdf5d5585c524764449fda2543d8130dd72d#writeContract

Please advise,
Thanks, Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on the link you end up on the site where all state-changing methods are shown. It shows me the `Connect to web3` button.

Click on it and use the wallet you are using. You need to have the private key for the following address: `0xe0cc4d92a460af4aa6a5b936a2ec21a036070901`

Go to the withdraw method, enter the amount of Ether you want to withdraw and your wallet should ask to sign a transaction.

Once you did that, you should get the ether, as soon the transaction is mined.

Comment: Thank you very much! This answer is spot on. 3.39 ETH to write frick that.

Comment: Happy to hear that it helped :) One more task left: Please accept my answer :)